# How to use `gather` or `reshape` to reshape dataframe to long format and keep rowname in R?

Tags: r

`df` example as below:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(q1 = c(2, 4, 5), q2 = c(1, 6, 3), q3 = c(3, 5, 6))
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  2  1  3
# 2  4  6  5
# 3  5  3  6

 gather(df)
#   key value
# 1  q1     2
# 2  q1     4
# 3  q1     5
# 4  q2     1
# 5  q2     6
# 6  q2     3
# 7  q3     3
# 8  q3     5
# 9  q3     6
```

As I need rowname to used in ggplot `fill=rowname`,I expected result as below:

```
#   key value  row
# 1  q1     2  1
# 2  q1     4  2
# 3  q1     5  3
# 4  q2     1  1
# 5  q2     6  2
# 6  q2     3  3
# 7  q3     3  1
# 8  q3     5  2
# 9  q3     6  3
```

I can only use `gather` and `reshape` functions, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rownames_to_column` or `rowid_to_column` before `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "row") %>%
  gather(key, value, -row)

#  row key value
#1   1  q1     2
#2   2  q1     4
#3   3  q1     5
#4   1  q2     1
#5   2  q2     6
#6   3  q2     3
#7   1  q3     3
#8   2  q3     5
#9   3  q3     6
```

---

Or another approach could be to add `row_number` per column after `gather`

```
gather(df) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

We may specify `times` in `reshape()`.

From `? reshape`:

> `times`    the values to use for a newly created timevar variable in long
>   format.

```
reshape(cbind(id=1:nrow(df), df), varying=2:4, sep="", direction="long", 
        v.names="q", timevar="key", times=names(df))
#      id key q
# 1.q1  1  q1 2
# 2.q1  2  q1 4
# 3.q1  3  q1 5
# 1.q2  1  q2 1
# 2.q2  2  q2 6
# 3.q2  3  q2 3
# 1.q3  1  q3 3
# 2.q3  2  q3 5
# 3.q3  3  q3 6
```